# How to call function when song finished in a Swift Playground

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, avplayer, swift-playground

I'm trying to call a function when a song finishes playing in a Swift playground. This is the code I'm using:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("playerDidFinishPlaying:")), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: winMusic)
```

However the function isn't called when the song finishes playing, and I don't know why? It's obviously not the same as in an iOS app.

```
var winMusic = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "win", ofType: "mp3")!)
var winPlayer: AVAudioPlayer? = nil
class Responder : NSObject {
    func playerDidFinishPlaying() {
        print("test")
        /* Nothing printed here */
    }
    func action(sender: UIButton) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Responder.playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: winMusic)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
        winPlayer!.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, how do I post the notification?

Comment: Can you share your playground code?

Comment: Alright @DaveWeston, code posted.

Comment: Alright, that's posted too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `winPlayer` delegate as,

```
winPlayer?.delegate = self
```

and implement the method

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if flag == true {
        // song finished successfully here
    }
}
```

where you will place the delegate is up to you.

Comment: Where do I put the the first line? I'm trying to put in the "action" function but I get an error saying "Cannot assign value of type 'Responder' to type 'AVAudioPlayerDelegate'", and I can't place it outside the Responder class otherwise I get an unresolved identifier error.

Comment: maybe, in `Responder` class's `init` method. but careful `delegate` expects a `UIVIewController`.

Comment: I would suggest, create a custom delegate here, in `Responder` class. let the parent controller handle the delegate.

Comment: There is no UIViewController. This is a Playground.

Comment: if you don't mind, @x4h1d could you explain with some sample code because I'm not following what you're saying about the custom delegate and I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: sure, check [this class](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p643ducking/ch27p912ducking/Player.swift).

Comment: [this is](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch16p687AVQueuePlayer/ch29p952AVQueuePlayer/ViewController.swift) how to use.

Answer (score 1):

An AVAudioPlayer does not post an AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime notification. You need to give the player a delegate. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudioplayerdelegate/1389160-audioplayerdidfinishplaying